# Use while loop to repeat 3 widgets. in flutter

Tags: loops, flutter, for-loop, while-loop

I want to repeat the following code with index values from 1 to n. How to do it in flutter ?

```
return ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      height: 15.0,
    ),
    new Image.asset(
      "assets/$name/$index.jpg",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 10.0,
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("$name $index",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 23,
                fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                color: Colors.black)),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0),
          width: 150.0,
          height: 50.0,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child: Text('Download',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.teal, width: 2, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Align the code properly, it is difficult to read. Expand your question on what to repeat 3 times. Do you want 3 listView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `ListView.builder` with `itemCount` and wrap `Column` 
code snippet

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                Image.network(
                  "https://picsum.photos/50?image=$index",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("$index",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 23,
                            fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                            color: Colors.black)),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0),
                      width: 150.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: null,
                        child: Text('Download',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.teal,
                                width: 2,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To show 3 times simple text using while loop.

```
 Widget getWidgets() {
    List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
        list.add(new Text(strings[i]));
        i++;
    }
    return Row(children:list);
}
```